# An appearance was requested without a variable text field

Tags: itext

I have come across this error while trying to fill in a form field. I really have no idea what it means and only occurs on some of the PDFs that I have.

I found it being thrown from AcroFields.java here:

```
if (!PdfName.CH.equals(fieldType))
        throw new DocumentException("An appearance was requested without a variable text field.");
```

Could anyone provide insight into this error and what is causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a very old version of iText, please upgrade!

In the most recent version, exceptions are localized:

```
if (!PdfName.CH.equals(fieldType))
    throw new DocumentException(MessageLocalization.getComposedMessage(
        "an.appearance.was.requested.without.a.variable.text.field"));
```

As for your question: the error tells you exactly what is happening. You are setting a value for a field for which two or more appearances are defined. However, the value you've chosen is an invalid value.

For instance: you have a check box for which the possible states are "Off" and "On", but you're trying to set the value "1". There is no appearance defined for the value "1" hence the exception.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I am, however, using the most recent version of iText.

Comment: Either you weren't accurate in your question, or you're making a mistake about using the most recent version of iText. All error messages have been localized quite a while ago; see my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I didn't copy that exception form the jar I was using, just found it through googling the error message.